# Alterar apenas o dia do registro

Tags: sql, sql-server

#### Cenário (exemplo):

Tenho a seguinte tabela:

```
ID | TIPO |    DATAINCLUSAO
 1 |  10  | 21/07/2018 09:34:51
 2 |  10  | 11/07/2018 11:15:25
 3 |  11  | 23/07/2018 01:52:31
 4 |  11  | 04/07/2018 23:24:52
 5 |  12  | 25/07/2018 03:43:33
```

---

#### Objetivo:

Gostaria de fazer um **update somente no dia**, deixando tudo dia `01`, por exemplo:

```
ID | TIPO |    DATAINCLUSAO
 1 |  10  | 01/07/2018 09:34:51
 2 |  10  | 01/07/2018 11:15:25
 3 |  11  | 01/07/2018 01:52:31
 4 |  11  | 01/07/2018 23:24:52
 5 |  12  | 01/07/2018 03:43:33
```

---

- Existe essa possibilidade **no próprio update**?
- Caso não, **quais alternativas**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considerando que `DATAINCLUSAO` é do tipo `datetime` você pode tentar o seguinte `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE tabela SET datainclusao = CONVERT(
    datetime, FORMAT(datainclusao, 'yyyy-MM-01 H:mm:ss')
);
```

Na função `FORMAT` estou formatando a data para um formato que o `datetime` irá entender, alterando a parte do dia.

Em seguida com `CONVERT` converto a data de volta para `datetime` porque o retorno do `FORMAT` é um `nvarchar`.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode usar a função [`DATEFROMPARTS`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), para mudar apenas o dia:

```
UPDATE tabela 
  SET datainclusao = datefromparts(year(datainclusao), month(datainclusao), 1)
```

Aqui, peguei o próprio ano e mês da data e só setei o dia como "1", visto que a função aceita (ano, mês, dia) como parâmetros.

Comment: ele não perdeira a hora nesse caso?

Comment: Realmente irá faltar as horas.  Mas se fosse o SQL Server 2012, teria a opção perfeita, como publiquei.

Comment: humm verdade @gmsantos tem razão, não me atentei a esse detalhe :)

Answer (score 1):

Você consegue atualizar o dado pelo `update` sim.

Você tem que transformar a data para texto, ajustar o dia e transformar novamente o valor para data.

Conheço deste jeito, se tiver outras, irei aprender.

#### Teste com SELECT

```
select 
  '01' + substring(convert(varchar(25), GETDATE(), 103), 3, 8),
  convert(varchar(12), GETDATE(), 114),
  convert(datetime, '01' + substring(convert(varchar(12), GETDATE(), 103), 3, 8), 103) + convert(datetime, convert(varchar(12), GETDATE(), 114), 114)
```

#### No UPDATE

```
update TABELA set DATAINCLUSAO = convert(datetime, '01' + substring(convert(varchar(12), GETDATE(), 103), 3, 8), 103) + convert(datetime, convert(varchar(12), GETDATE(), 114), 114)
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Complementando respostas:

A partir do **SQL Server 2012**, existe a função: [`DATETIMEFROMPARTS`](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/datetimefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

**Sintaxe:**

```
DATETIMEFROMPARTS ( year, month, day, hour, minute, seconds, milliseconds )
```

**Exemplo:**

```
UPDATE tabela 
  SET DATAINCLUSAO = DATETIMEFROMPARTS(YEAR(DATAINCLUSAO), MONTH(DATAINCLUSAO), 1, DATEPART(HOUR, DATAINCLUSAO), DATEPART(MINUTE, DATAINCLUSAO), DATEPART(SECOND, DATAINCLUSAO), DATEPART(MILLISECOND, DATAINCLUSAO))
```

PS: *poderia usar somente o DATEPART para buscar todas as partes*.

---

#### Outras funções utilizadas:

[DATEPART](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/functions/datepart-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)